# Matplotlib animation not showing (Gradient Descent Test)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I tried to create a `matplotlib` animation to practice using gradient descent to do linear regression. However I can't get the animation to work.

I managed to get the animation to work by using `anim.show()` but this caused an `AttributeError` as the animation class does not have a method. No idea why this actually causes the animation to work

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def main():
    # Initialize Dataset
    X = 10*np.random.rand(50)
    y = 8*X + 1 + 2.5*np.random.randn(50)
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.train(X,y)
    model.animate(X,y)

class LinearRegression():
    # Using Gradient Descent for Linear Regression
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, epochs=100):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.a_0 = 0
        self.a_1 = 0
        self.w_list = []

    def train(self, X, y):
        n = X.shape[0]

        for i in range(self.epochs):
            self.w_list.append([self.a_0,self.a_1])
            y_train = self.a_0 + self.a_1 * X
            error = y - y_train        # Whether you use y_train - y or y - y_train will make a difference
            mse = np.sum(error ** 2) / n
            self.a_0 -= -2/n * np.sum(error) * self.learning_rate
            self.a_1 -= -2/n * np.sum(error * X) * self.learning_rate

            #if i%10 == 0:
            #   print("MSE",str(i)+":", mse)
        self.w_list = np.array(self.w_list)

    def animate(self, X, y):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.scatter(X,y)
        plot_range = np.array(range(int(min(X))-1,int(max(X))+3))
        a_0,a_1 = self.w_list[0,]
        y_plot = plot_range*a_1 + a_0
        ln, = ax.plot(plot_range, y_plot, color="red", label="Best Fit")

        def animator(frame):
            a_0, a_1 = self.w_list[frame,]
            y_plot = plot_range * a_1 + a_0
            ln.set_data(plot_range,y_plot)


        print("Launching Animation")
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func = animator, frames = self.epochs)
        anim.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The short answer: Assign the animation to an instance variable, `self.ani = FuncAnimation(...)`. Also probably need to call `plt.show()` inside `main()`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Assigning as an instance variable solved the problem. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Yes, `anim` is a local variable inside `animate`. It will be lost once that function finishes. By producing an error you prevented that function to return, which led to the animation working (probably you are using interactive mode somehow, maybe inside of IPython?).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `plt.show()` to open the plot window.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def main():
    # Initialize Dataset
    X = 10*np.random.rand(50)
    y = 8*X + 1 + 2.5*np.random.randn(50)
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.train(X,y)
    model.animate(X,y)

class LinearRegression():
    # Using Gradient Descent for Linear Regression
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, epochs=100):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.a_0 = 0
        self.a_1 = 0
        self.w_list = []

    def train(self, X, y):
        n = X.shape[0]

        for i in range(self.epochs):
            self.w_list.append([self.a_0,self.a_1])
            y_train = self.a_0 + self.a_1 * X
            error = y - y_train        # Whether you use y_train - y or y - y_train will make a difference
            mse = np.sum(error ** 2) / n
            self.a_0 -= -2/n * np.sum(error) * self.learning_rate
            self.a_1 -= -2/n * np.sum(error * X) * self.learning_rate

            #if i%10 == 0:
            #   print("MSE",str(i)+":", mse)
        self.w_list = np.array(self.w_list)

    def animate(self, X, y):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.scatter(X,y)
        plot_range = np.array(range(int(min(X))-1,int(max(X))+3))
        a_0,a_1 = self.w_list[0,]
        y_plot = plot_range*a_1 + a_0
        ln, = ax.plot(plot_range, y_plot, color="red", label="Best Fit")

        def animator(frame):
            a_0, a_1 = self.w_list[frame,]
            y_plot = plot_range * a_1 + a_0
            ln.set_data(plot_range,y_plot)


        print("Launching Animation")
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func = animator, frames = self.epochs)
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```